# How to run certain script just once at user end?

Tags: javascript, html

For example, when the user enter URL for the first time,
the popup like "Like our page on FB" will appear.

when the user go around the website and returns to the top page,
the upper popup shouldn't appear.

If I use window.onload or script,
it will appear each time while loading the page.

Is there any other way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Use cookies to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this [using cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html). Go to my [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/UYsFL/1/) and you'll see the message, then, if you refresh you wont!

```js
//check if we've asked them before (in the last 5 minutes)
if (!(new RegExp('homeFacebookMessage=true')).test(document.cookie)) {
    //take a temporary (5min) note that we've asked them
    document.cookie = 'homeFacebookMessage=true;path=/;max-age=' + 5 * 60 + ';';
    //ask them (your code here)
    alert('Like us on faceface!');
}
```

You could even try some [Web Storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage), which will work all the way down to IE8. Here's [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8DBaT/1/).

```js
//check if we have asked them already
if (!localStorage.getItem('homeFacebookMessage')) {
    //make a note that we've asked them
    localStorage.setItem('homeFacebookMessage', 'true');
    //ask them (your code here)
    alert('Like us on faceface!');
}
```

The difference with `localStorage` is that it's permanent, and won't remind the user to 'like' after 5minutes (when our cookie expires in the first example).
However, if you really like the web storage method you could assign a date/time to `homeFacebookMessage`, and check how long ago it was instead of simply testing its existence to get the same effect.

Comment: upvoted everyone for giving him good advice. I've implemented actual demo's for him as an example

Comment: @KapilManandhar then hit the upward triangle or the tick next to the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

You can either use cookies: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Or HTML5 webstorage: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Cookies are much more supported though...

The basic idea is that you store a cookie saying that you displayed the popup and whenever you reload the homepage you check if the cookie exists. If it exists, no popup is needed, otherwise you show the popup.

Comment: upvoted for good advice, I was implementing an example and comparison whilst you answered, my answer is now up

Comment: Thank you for sharing the knowledge.Should be using. not much reputation for the vote. +1 for you! Thumps up.